# How to perform additional operation on a trainable variable in Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

My training loop is like following,

***::pseudocode***

```
define the graph 
define session
get_model()
get_optimizers()
for i in range(epoch):
    for j in range(num_of_batches):
        x,y = get_value()
        sess.run()  # runs a MLP based on some parameter
        sess.run()  # runs similar MLP based on some different parameter
        ---normalize some weight of MLP---
```

Now I am stuck in the portion of **"normalize some weight of MLP"**

How should I define my normalization code snippet in my model class? I have tried the following way,

```
W_trans = tf.Variable(
            identity,
            name="trans",
            dtype=tf.float32)
self.theta_M.append(W_trans)
W_trans = tf.norm(W_trans)
```

I have also tried to incorporate this by `tf.assign()` but it can not be used if I want to optimized my model based on the parameter `W_trans`.

Comment: Can't you incorporate `normalization` of the `weights` with the graph?

Comment: Yes. But my question is how to do that normalization after completing one training step.

Comment: Well, you can perform your operations on the `Variable` and just pass it in the `feed_dict` parameter just as you would for any other placeholder. I know that `feed_dict` accepts values for variable, but I can't say whether that value will be available for further computation. You can try that yourself.